# At "Create Role" what AWS service to chose for creating Custom Management Keys (CMK)?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am new to AWS. My task is create a KMS management role that would be used for creating Custom Management Keys.

I am on the step of “Create Role”.  I need to choose the service that will use this role.

There are about 40 options, such as EC2, EC2 Container Service, EMR, S3. What is the most logical service?

Comment: I think IAM is what you're looking for. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/control-access-overview.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a Role in AWS IAM, that Role must then be used with something else. E.g. you may have an EC2 instance (a server) that has a Role assigned to it. Anything running inside that EC2 instance will then have the permissions assigned to that role. Same is true about AWS Lambda Functions and other services.

In this case, you are creating a Role, so later you would create an application/service/function that performs CMK creation tasks for you. Your role will be assigned to your application. Therefore, you only have to decide where your application is supposed to run?

If it is going to run inside EC2, you should choose the Principal in your policy as EC2 service. If it is Lambda, choose Lambda, and so forth...

Notice, you can specify AWS accounts (root), IAM users, IAM roles, and some AWS services as principals in a key policy. IAM groups are not valid principals.

See here for more info:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policies.html